# Outlook VBScript run as rule

Tags: vbscript, outlook-2010

I'm a new user, so please go gentle on me.

I have created an Outlook rule that runs the below script which writes some of the email message properties to an SQL table.

The connection is working fine, when I run this as a macro on a selected message, it works fine... but when I leave it to run as a rule, it just keeps writing the currently selected email...

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong...

Code is below :

```
Sub TEST_TO_SQL(Item As MailItem)

Dim sSubject As String
Dim sTo As String
Dim sFrom As String
Dim sMsgeID As String
Dim sRcvd As Date

Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
sSubject = Item.Subject
sTo = Item.ReceivedByName
sFrom = Item.SenderEmailAddress
sMsgID = Item.EntryID
sRcvd = Item.ReceivedTime

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open _
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
    "Data Source=SQLSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
    "Trusted_Connection=Yes;" & _
    "InitialCatalog=SQLDB;" & _
    "User ID=sa;Password=password;"
objRecordSet.Open _
    "INSERT INTO [SQLDB].[dbo].[EMAIL_Log] (LogCompanyID, LogSubject, LogStartDate, LogEndDate, LogShortDesc, LogLongDesc, LogFrom, LogTo, LogMessageID, LogCategory1)" & _
    "VALUES ('11'," & "'" & sSubject & "'" & ", " & "'" & Format(sRcvd, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "'" & ", '', 'short desc', 'Long Desc', " & "'" & sFrom & "'" & ", " & "'" & sTo & "'" & ", " & "'" & sMsgID & "'" & ", '47')", objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're always using the currently selected mail item. Remove the line:

```
Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

Then `Item` will be the one passed in to the `Sub`